# Working example for MediaElementAudioSourceNode with Chrome Canary?

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, w3c

I'm experimenting with the [W3C Web Audio API](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2003/trunk/samples/audio/specification/specification.html) implemented and enabled in Google Chrome Canary builds. (i have 15.0.865.0 canary on Windows 7 x64 at the moment) [Demo applications](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html) work just fine.

I like to use [`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2003/trunk/samples/audio/specification/specification.html#MediaElementAudioSourceNode-section) because i like to play a larger OGG music. For such audio files the API says that i should use this instead of `AudioBufferSourceNode`.

I've written a very simple example:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'dubfx.ogg');

      var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
      var streamingAudioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
      streamingAudioSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
  </script>
```

However i just hear clicks instead of actual audio. I see no errors in the JavaScript console so i guess the code is okay, maybe some initialization is missing. If i call `audioElement.play()` instead of the routing through the Web Audio API, the music plays just fine. Did i miss something or maybe the current WebKit implementation is broken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just talked to Chris Rogers (the spec editor) about this today. The `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` is exposed in Canary/Chromium builds but the internals are not hooked up yet. It'll be a while longer before you can use the `<audio>` tag with the Web Audio API.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a page where i can follow the development of the Web Audio API in Chrome?

Comment: This is not a comprehensive list, but you can track the progress of bugs [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=owner%3Acrogers+OR+%22web+audio%22&colspec=ID+Stars+Pri+Area+Feature+Type+Status+Summary+Modified+Owner+Mstone+OS&x=mstone&y=area&cells=tiles). Another great place is the [spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) which is up to date. Lastly, there's the Audio Working Group mailing list, which is listed on that page.

Comment: It's now finally supported in Chrome 18 (currently Canary)! See: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs

Comment: is 'MediaElementAudioSourceNode' supported only from Chrome 30(stable)? Ref:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/_zdJBwP4vNU/6Oy-GkbAi3UJ.