# Webkit audio Api createMediaElement Source

Tags: api, audio, webkit

with reference to [Working example for MediaElementAudioSourceNode with Chrome Canary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233973/working-example-for-mediaelementaudiosourcenode-with-chrome-canary)

anything ever came of this? I get a JS error

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'createMediaElementSource'

I'm using the latest chrome

Answer (score 1):

It's now finally supported in Chrome 18 (currently Canary)!

See this article: [HTML5Rocks Updates - HTML5  and the Web Audio API are BFFs!](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs)