# Play an AudioBufferSourceNode twice?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Should I be able to use the same `AudioBufferSourceNode` to play a sound multiple times? For some reason, calling `noteGrainOn` a second time doesn't play audio, even with an intervening `noteOff`.

This code only plays the sound once:

```
var node = audioContext.createBufferSource()
node.buffer = audioBuffer
node.connect(audioContext.destination)

var now = audioContext.currentTime
node.noteGrainOn(now, 0, 2)
node.noteOff(now + 2)
node.noteGrainOn(now + 3, 0, 2)
node.noteOff(now + 5)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Once you've played back a source node, you can't reuse it. You need to create another `AudioBufferSourceNode` with the same buffer. Check out the [Web Audio FAQ](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ) for more info (see the noteOn() question).

Comment: As you says, this seem not possible http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/#toc-volume need to reload. I have also trouble reloading using a currentime // play = function() { source.noteOn(now); }, pause = function() { now = audioContext.currentTime; source.noteOff(0); }

Answer (score 1):

I have some hack to toggle play/pause easily :)
You can map the audio to an existing audio tag directly and use the control on it

```
<audio id="sound" src="./test.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>

var audioElement = document.getElementById('sound');
source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
/* ... */
audioElement.pause();
```

My example running here : http://www.b2bweb.fr/bonus/Braincer/
I currently use Chrome build 18.0.xxxx

Others refs :

- [Working example for MediaElementAudioSourceNode with Chrome Canary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233973/working-example-for-mediaelementaudiosourcenode-with-chrome-canary)
- http://updates.html5rocks.com/tag/webaudio